# Hibernate Cascade option to delete parent record but not orphan

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, cascade

I have a one-to-many relationship in `Product` and `Product_Order`. I want to use cascade such that on deleting Product record from Product it does not delete already saved record from `Product_Order`, but just make them orphan in child table. What should I use and how?

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
    private Set<ProductOrder> productOrder;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code snippet form hibernate **CascadeType** class.
Option **All** includes all the below operations.

As you can clearly see, **DELETE** corresponds to Hibernate and not JPA, so JPA uses **(orphanRemoval=true)** option to delete child record.

**From Hibernate**

```
public enum CascadeType {
        /**
         * Includes all types listed here.
         */
        ALL,
        /**
         * Corresponds to {@link javax.persistence.CascadeType#PERSIST}.
         */
        PERSIST,
        /**
         * Corresponds to {@link javax.persistence.CascadeType#MERGE}.
         */
        MERGE,
        /**
         * Corresponds to {@link javax.persistence.CascadeType#REMOVE}.
         */
        REMOVE,
        /**
         * Corresponds to {@link javax.persistence.CascadeType#REFRESH}.
         */
        REFRESH,
        /**
         * Corresponds to the Hibernate native DELETE action.
         */
        DELETE,
        /**
         * Corresponds to the Hibernate native SAVE_UPDATE (direct reattachment) action.
         */
        SAVE_UPDATE,
        /**
         * Corresponds to the Hibernate native REPLICATE action.
         */
        REPLICATE,
        /**
         * Hibernate originally handled orphan removal as a specialized cascade.
         *
         * @deprecated use @OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true) or @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
         */
        @Deprecated
        DELETE_ORPHAN,
        /**
         * Corresponds to the Hibernate native LOCK action.
         */
        LOCK,
        /**
         * JPA originally planned on calling DETACH EVICT.
         *
         * @deprecated use javax.persistence.CascadeType.DETACH
         */
        @Deprecated
        EVICT,
        /**
         * Corresponds to {@link javax.persistence.CascadeType#REFRESH}.
         */
        DETACH
    }
```

**From JPA**

```
public enum CascadeType {

    /** Cascade all operations */
    ALL,

    /** Cascade persist operation */
    PERSIST,

    /** Cascade merge operation */
    MERGE,

    /** Cascade remove operation */
    REMOVE,

    /** Cascade refresh operation */
    REFRESH,

    /**
     * Cascade detach operation
     *
     * @since Java Persistence 2.0
     *
     */
    DETACH
}
```

Hope now things should be much clear

Comment: Hey @Ankur I used `DELETE` but it has also deleted record from its foreign key records from child table. Any other options?

Comment: Right now I have implemented a workaround of deleting records. Added a boolean field `isDeleted` and setting it true or false on deleting.

Comment: Thanks for making it more clear Ankur. Could you please tell me which jar or maven artifact should I use to get `(orphanRemoval=true)`. Currently I am using `org.hibernate.javax.persistence.hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final` and not getting required options.

Comment: @Salim

hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final-sources.jar
Maven Artifact

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

In your delete() of your ProductDao class, you will need to get the productOrder set, iterate through each order, set each order's product to null, update it in database. Something like this:

```
for (ProductOrder order : product.getProductOrder())
{
    order.setProduct(null);
    ProductOrderDao.update(order);
}
session.delete(product);
```

This may work, but I don't recommend this. Leaving orphan objects in your database will probably make it messy and therefore hard to manage in future.

Comment: Thanks Tony for your suggestion but right now I am soft deleting parent records.

Comment: I did not gave you negative marks. probably someone else.